# python no module named playsound

Tags: python, raspbian

Trying to get some speechrecognition going here on a raspberry pi running raspbian os but no matter what I do im getting the error "no module named playsound".
I'm using pip install playsound and getting successful install.
Im using pip freeze | grep play and getting playsound ==1.2.2.
I have loaded up the latest Raspbian os but same results.
the playsound files are where the should be .
I have tried pip3 install.
I have tried uninstall of both and reinstall on just pip.
I have upgraded pip and raspbian.
the code is the default nothing special.
Out of ideas and any help would be appreciated here.

```
import os
import time
import playsound
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS

def speak(text):
   tts = gTTS(text=text, lang="en-uk")
   filename = "voice.mp3"
   tts.save(filename)
   playsound.playsound(filename)

speak("hello")
```

Comment: What does `python --version` and `pip --version` give you? also how are you calling the code?

Comment: Both latest version. Pi not on atm to for exact version but that was also a step to make sure. Convinced is a raspberry pi issue going to spin um some vms and test today.

Answer (score 1):

If you run your python program with `python3 {python_file}.py`, try to use

```
python3 -m pip install
```

Or if you run your python program with `python {python_file}.py`, use

```
python -m pip install
```

This will guarantee that the pip is referring to the exact python version you are using.

Comment: Same issue unfortunately. I uninstalled bit python and python 3 playsound to be sure. The ran first python3 -m pip install playsound and got a successful but still no module named error show up. I have moved on to pygame module now as it is not giving any such errors but thank you

Answer (score 0):

After mucking about for quite some time I never got playsound working but had no issues with pydub. With pydub it just worked as intended.